# My http response is too large to keep in memory. How can I stream the response in a Camel route?

Tags: rest, apache-camel, bytearrayoutputstream

We are implementing Camel routes to handle service requests. 
We have the requirement to deliver a huge response to a certain request. This response can be that large that it may cause memory problems.
For now we write the response in a file, move that file to an external ftp server and return the name and location of the file as the http response.
What I really like to do is to stream the response via the http response in Camel. Unfortunately I could not find any doc/samples on how to do that.

This is our current implementation:

```
.rest(BASE_URL_VERSION)
.get("/generic/xxxxxx").produces(MIME_MEDIA_TYPE_JSON)
.route()
.process(new ResponseBuilderProcessor())  // this creates the temp file
.to(uriOut)                               // this moves the file to the external ftp
.process(new AnswerProcessor());         // provides the response where the file location is mentioned
```

Is this doable? How?

Answer (score 0):

Consider making your service async

If the request is proper make the request as accepted(http 202) & give the client the details of the reponse availability (may be in a JMS queue  or the file location as you mentioned) . The queue ID  or file location can be send as response .

The client will hit the Queue or file location after a time interval & get the response if it is available .